# Yeoman gulp webapp change styles directory name

Tags: gulp, yeoman

I am developing a theme using the Yeoman Gulp Webapp Generator. The CMS requires a directory called "css" instead of "styles". It sounds simple enough but for some reason I can't get the dist/styles to be dist/css.

From a brand new build I changed the styles directory name to css and them in the gulpfile I searched and replaced all

```
app/styles
```

to

```
app/css
```

This kind of works, the directory in app is now named css but the directory name in dist remains as styles.

I think it gets the name from the .tmp directory? but I'm not sure. If I rename the .tmp/styles to .tmp/css the files are ignored and not transferred to dist.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change `.tmp/styles` in your `gulpfile.js` to `.tmp/css` and change this part of `index.html`:

```
<!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

to this:

```
<!-- build:css css/main.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

However, if you all you need to do is end up with `dist/css`, you don't have to change `app/styles` to `app/css` and all that, you can just change this part of `index.html`:

```
<!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
```

to this:

```
<!-- build:css css/main.css -->
```

That path refers to where in the `dist` directory will those styles be saved.